# Azure Devops pipeline -> how to priorities one pipeline over another in build queue

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

we have only one agent and several pipelines.
Is it possible to set a rule so that in case of a queue, pipelien A will always run before pipeline B?

The situation:

Pipeline A is running, with 2 jobs:
Job 1 triggering pipeline B.
We want the agent to run Pipelien B before running Job 2 on pipeline A..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All the attempts are based on one agent.

Separate your Pipeline A's 2 jobs into 2 stages.

[image]

Using "Agentless job" Approvals and checks defined in the Variable Group to get the latest build for Pipeline B: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/latest/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

[image]

[image]

Trigger Pipeline B after Job 1 in Pipeline A.

Define the variable group in Stage 2:

```
- stage: Prod
  variables:
  - group: 1013
  jobs:
  - job: CheckBuildSuccess
    steps:    
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          # Write your PowerShell commands here.
          
          Write-Host "Hello World"
```

This check will start before stage 2 to check the latest build for pipeline B.

Check the test run result:

[image]